# Getting indexof arraylist of class. java

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

I have class listA:

```
public class lista {
            int i;
            String name;

            public lista(int i, String name)
            {
                this.i = i;
                this.name = name;
            }
    }
```

I made ArrayList from this class.

```
 public static ArrayList<lista> friends;
```

Adding some date:
14 - Adam
2 - John
35 - Arnold
74 - x
54 - x

and i want to get IndexOf 74 and change name from x to Catrina.

How to do it?

```
friends.get(friends.indexOf(??)) = "catarina";
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you would be better of using a `Map` as they are much better equipped to handle key value pairs which is what you have here.

```
Map<Integer, String> friends = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

friends.put(14, "Adam");

friends.get(14); //Adam

friends.put(14, "John");

friends.get(14); //Now John
```

Comment: You beat me with the map approach, I was still typing through the steps with the old ones...

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. The `i` in your class `lista` is not the index of where it is in the list.

First of all, you have to change your class. This is not nice coding.

```
public class Friend { 
       //note1: Class Names Start With Capital Letter!
       //note2: Class names have meaning!

        private int i; //notice private modifier. 
        private String name; //notice private modifier.

        public Friend (int i, String name)
        {
            this.i = i;
            this.name = name;
        }
        /* getter and setter methods */
        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }
        public String getName()
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name)
            this.name = name;
        }
      /* don't forget equals() and hashCode() */

}
```

Of course, a proper equals() and hashCode() method is crucial to be able to workwith them properly - but there is an abundance of materials regarding this subject on the net...

Given that class, you have to traverse the list to find the elements:

```
for(Friend friend: friends) {
    if(&& friend.getI()==74) {
        friend.setName("Cristina");
    }
}
```

But from here, there are still some improvements to make. [The approach of cowls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15221201/1667004) is in the right direction, but I'd take it one step further, by using a `Map<Integer, Friend>`:

```
//create Map
Map<Intger, Friend> friends = new HashMap<Integer, Friend>();
//note: use interface for declaring variables where possible to hide implementation specifics!

//add friends:
friends.put(75, new Friend(75,"a")); 
//... left ot others for brevity

//modify part:
Friend f = friends.get(75);
if(f!=null) { //always check for null
   f.setName("Christina");
}
```

What more do you get compared to cowls' approach? If you want to add fields to the `Friend` class - you are free to do that without pain of having to deal with converting everything...